# new Thread(method) vs new Thread(new ThreadStart(method))?

Tags: c#, multithreading

What is the difference between...

```
Thread MyThread = new Thread(ChangeColor);
```

vs.

```
Thread MyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ChangeColor));
```

Both are starting a new thread but is there a difference between doing it one way vs. the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing.  You're effectively asking the difference between:

```
ThreadStart threadStart = ChangeColor;
```

and

```
ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(ChangeColor);
```

The first is an implicit method group conversion.  Both result in the same compiled code.